# Support back button in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to support back button, while the design on my app is navigation drawer. The problem is the fragments doesn't pushed into backstack, but I solved it:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack();
```

but the problem, is when I'm clicking the back button - the title keep. I solved it too with

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(str);
```

but still, the problem is in the navigation list - on the left side. it doesn't changed appropriate to back button (just stay as it was).
Actually, my question is how can i get backStack top - so than i can easily solve it, or if you have another solution.

Comment: Any chance of a picture? It'll help me see what you want.

Comment: Not sure what really is the problem, why can't you add fragments from the navigation drawer to the backstack?

Comment: I dont think you got me. In navigation drawer, if you open the list on the left side, you see your choise - your current fragment. i need to change it, rely on where you were, depends when you click back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bit late but still for people who don't know how to it. I think this will solve your problem:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      
    selectItem(position);       
}

public void selectItem(int position) {      
    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);

    String[] simple_array = fragment_items.toArray(new String[fragment_items.size()]);
    setTitle(simple_array[position]);
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

so when I click on an item in the listview of the navigation drawer, it calls the function selectItem with the parameter position. In the selectItem method I converted my arraylist to a normal array to set my title. The position in your listview is the same as the positions in your array. So simple_array[0] is equal to you first list item. Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

write the line after setContentView()

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and use the

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: {
        CommonFunctions.writeLogs(getApplicationContext(), CONFIG, LOGGER,
                "onCreateOptionsMenu()" + "home");

        finish();
  }

  break;
    }

 default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
```

}

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I dont think you got me. In navigation drawer, if you open the list on the left side, you see your choise - your current fragment. i need to change it, rely on where you were, depends when you click back button.